# Where can I find a type safe UnmodifiableCollections implementation?

Tags: java, collections

I want to return an unmoifiable collection while getting type safety.  I can’t seem to find this even though I would expect it to be easy to do.

Lets say I have a class Foo which contains a *large* collection of classes Bar inside of it, large enough that it would take awhile to clone.  I expect to want to iterate over every element of Bar in Foo as part of a tight loop, so I have a getBars() method on my Foo object

I don’t want to pass the collection within foo directly to someone calling the getBar() because that would allow anyone to modify the collection, which is not safe.  So my options are

1)  Copy my Foo collection into a new collection
2)  Return Collections.unmodifiableCollections
The first option requires copying everything, that’s expensive in a tight loop, and I don’t anticipate needing to modify the collection after it’s returned.  The second option does what I want, but it doesn’t make it obvious to the end user that happened.  If someone later decides they want to modify the collection returned by getBar for some reason they will get an exception the moment the call add or remove, which is in no way clearly documented by the code (yes the API would document it, but not the same).

What I would like is to have an UnmodifiableCollection class which wraps my actual collection and only makes visible the getters but not the setters.  It would be fast since it’s only wrapping, not copying, the underlying collection, and it would be self documenting that you can not modify the collection, no one gets unexpected runtime exceptions later.

What I want to know is does this exist!?  It seems so basic that Guava should have it, but I can’t find it anywhere.  If it doesn’t exist is there some reason why this is harder or less useful to do that I imagine it would be?
Ps. Guava immutableCollections all do copies of the underlying collection as far as I am aware, so their equivalent to option 1 above

Comment: "*large enough that it would take awhile to clone*" => how large? Unless it has many millions of entries, a copy will be fast.

Comment: The issue is that the `Collection` interface specifies those methods. So you can either have a class with no setters or have something that's compatible with the Collections framework. It would have been nice to have the `Collection` interface split into a getter-only part and a subinterface with setters that extended that, but that might have been too complex and not needed enough for inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible by the java.util.Collections API design.

All standard collection API's are *designed* as mutable, so there is *nothing* you can do about it as long as you want to use the collection interfaces.

You can either switch to return (your own implementation of) Enumeration (somewhat outdated interface), or a simple Iterator (getBarIterator() instead of getBarList()). That avoid all (or most) implications of having any add / remove methods. You expose significantly less information/functionality that way, which may be a problem or desired, depending on use case. In case of Iterator, you still have the remove() method on the iterator that the client could try to use just to get an UnsupportedOperationException()/IllegalStateException().

It has bugged me for a long time that reading and modifying method of the collections API's are all in the same interface. For whatever reason the API designers chose to design it the way it is, and since its widely established now it can't be changed (without breaking compatibility, which is as good as "unchangeable").

If none of that fits and you value clean API safety above using a standard API, roll your own immutable API.

Edit:
My own personal solution to this dilema was to create a Set of *alterable* wrappers. They implement the normal collection API (List, Set, Map), and initially they just delegate everything to their *source* collection. On the first write attempt, they copy their source and function as normal independent collections after that. Be warned that the implementation, especially of iterator().remove() can be tricky.

Comment: For your edit, it's kind of like `CopyOnWriteArrayList` but for everything?

Comment: Yes, vaguely. The difference is that the alterable wrapper is not aimed at or (by itself) suitable for multithreaded access.

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to just cast your collection to a type that doesn't allow mutation? For example:

```
static <T> List<? extends T> unmodifiable(List<T> list) {
    return (List<? extends T>)list;
}

List<? extends String> list = unmodifiable(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
list.add("four"); // compilation error!
list.set(0, "bar"); // another compilation error!
String first = list.get(0); // but I can read Strings out of my List, at least
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `Collections.unmodifiableCollections` then the wrapper collection returns will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`

And if you create a standard wrapper then you will end up at the same implementation like Collections.unmodifiableCollections

But if you create your own wrapper with different methods like standards, you will end up implementing separate classes 
or exposing own classes and interfaces for Collections to your clients, that may be mix your implementation between standard and specific.

I think the simple approach is to use `Collections.unmodifiableCollections` or cloning and go with standard Java developments 
finally implements your own wrapper classes and methods.

**But if you create your own wrapper with different methods as in standard collections,
It will not be a wrapper of collection it will be an own class that use collections internally.**

You can simply return your own object that implements your specific classes and does not disperses your clients of naming.